# Swing drawing large circles causing slowdown

Tags: java, swing, graphics

Ive run into a dilema. I want to be able to draw quite a few transparent medium sized circles. What seems to happen however is that when I draw large circles with swing. How should I go about drawing these larger circles

Code that shows this which simply draws a bunch of small circles or a lot of large ones. I used fraps to check the fps I don't know how to do it any other way, a suggestion would be much appreciated on that front as well.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.image.*; 
import java.io.*; 
import javax.imageio.*; 
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class PhysicsGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println();
        Game frame = new Game();
    }
}

class Game extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    private Timer myTimer;   
    private GamePanel panel;

    public Game() {
        super("Things.py");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(1000,800);
        panel = new GamePanel(this);
        add(panel);
        myTimer = new Timer(15, this);
        myTimer.start();

        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
        panel.repaint();        
    }
}

class GamePanel extends JPanel{

    private Game mainframe;

    public GamePanel(Game m){
        mainframe=m;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics gg){
        Graphics2D g=(Graphics2D) gg;
        for (int i=0;i<100;i++){
            g.fillOval(10,10,100,100);
            //g.fillOval(10,10,1000,1000);// this takes significantly longer
        }

    }

    public void addNotify() {
        super.addNotify();
    }
```

Comment: The size of your circle is larger than the size of your panel, so I would guess that clipping is involved when you paint the circle. Maybe try to may sure that the circle fits into the panel so you don't have to worry about clipping. Just a wild guess.

Comment: When the circle is slightly smaller than the panel it's also slower, although a bit less so. My guess is that it just has to redraw a larger area of the panel the larger the circle is.

Comment: "I used fraps to check the fps I don't know how to do it any other way". I added `System.currentTimeMillis()` at the start and end of `paintComponent` and printed the difference. For the small circles, a `paintComponent` execution takes 1-4 ms, for the large ones it takes 30-34 ms (on my computer).

Comment: [This](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) might offer some help.

Comment: Yeah i don't think its because its larger than the screen. But i would not have thought it would be such a big performance hit that is caused from more pixels being coloured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's for a game, maybe you could consider replacing the use of the drawing primitive with (pre-computed) pictures with alpha layer (for transparency).

You can create the images with BufferedImages, draw on them, retrieve them
when needed, and draw them with g.drawImage ?

I guess both the drawing and the clipping will be more efficient then.